# how can I add main link to sublink html, so that link can be called?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing

this is my code that gives a list of particular news links from HTML page, it contains only resource name and parameters, I want to include main domain name so that link can be operatable.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_cric_info_articles():

    cricinfo_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/news.html"

    r = requests.get(cricinfo_article_link)
    cricinfo_article_html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(cricinfo_article_html, "html.parser")
    # print(soup.prettify())

    cric_info_items = soup.find_all("h2",
                                    {"class": "story-title"})
    cricinfo_article_dict = {}

    for div in cric_info_items:
        cricinfo_article_dict[div.find('a').string] = div.find('a')['href']

    return cricinfo_article_dict


print(get_cric_info_articles())
```

what I'm getting `{'Bell-Drummond leads MCC in curtain-raiser': '/ci/content/story/1135157.html', 'Scotland pick Brad Wheal, Chris Sole for World Cup qualifiers': '/scotland/content/story/1135152.html', 'Newlands working to be water independent': '/southafrica/content/story/1135120.html'}`

I'm trying to attach this `'/ci/content/story/1135157.html'`to `http://www.espncricinfo.com/`
so the final link will be http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/1135157.html', how can I do this? sorry for the long post

changes I did

```
for div in cric_info_items:
        a = div.find('a')['href']
        b = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/'
        c = urljoin(b,a)
        cricinfo_article_dict[div.find('a').string] = c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `urllib.parse` module for this:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
urljoin('http://www.espncricinfo.com/', '/ci/content/story/1135157.html')
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
# if protocol is not specified in the link, assume it's relative
for div in cric_info_items:
    url = div.find('a')['href']
    if "://" not in url:
        url = cricinfo_article_link + url
    cricinfo_article_dict[div.find('a').string] = url
...
```

or, using dict comprehension:

```
return {
    div.find('a').string : ("" if "://" in div.find('a')['href'] else cricinfo_article_link) + div.find('a')['href']
    for div in soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "story-title"})
}
```

Upd: a potential border case is links starting with `//`, e.g. `//google.com/?q=foo`. This type of links sometimes is used for resources (css and javascript) and is not common for external links. However, you might want to handle this as well

Comment: what is url here?, I didn't get your method